# Is Solr 4.0 capable of using 'join" for multiple core?

Tags: join, solr, lucene

I notice Solr 4.0 has introduced 'join' feature for documents having relationships. this is great, however, I notice examples given by http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join are for single core which all documents are in single index.

Does anybody know if I can use 'join' for multiple core?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[This comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2272?focusedCommentId=13024918&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-13024918) says it's possible by using:

```
{!join from=fromField to=toField fromIndex=fromCoreName}fromQuery
```

I tried it myself, and here's a more detailed example:
Have two cores

- brands {id,name}
- products {id, name, brand_id}

**BRANDS**: {1, Apple}, {2, Samsung}, {3, HTC}

**PRODUCTS**: {1, iPhone, 1}, {2, iPad, 1}, {3, Galaxy S3, 2}, {4, Galaxy Note, 2}, {5, One X, 3}

http://example.com:8999/solr/brands/select?q=*:*&fq={!join from=brand_id to=id fromIndex=products}name:iPad

This translates to something like:

```
SELECT b.* FROM brands b
       INNER JOIN products p ON b.id=p.brand_id
       WHERE p.name="iPad";
```

Result will be: {id: "1", name:"Apple"}

Comment: Thx for the nice example. More precisely the SQL equivalent is `SELECT b.* FROM brands b
       INNER JOIN products p ON b.id=p.brand_id
       WHERE p.name="iPad";` since Solr can't give the fields of the fromCore :-(

Comment: The query is invalid, it should be: `q=name:iPad&fq={!join from=brand_id to=id fromIndex=products}` or `q=*:*&fq={!join from=brand_id to=id fromIndex=products}name:iPad`. `q=:` is invalid.

Comment: @zengr:   Yes, the *:* is displayed as a formatting option, it's fixed now.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this if for example the products.id was an array of ids?

Comment: @Adam I believe so, yes.