# Is JOIN possible between two indexes on different ports in SOLR?

Tags: join, solr

JOIN can be made between multiple cores([Is Solr 4.0 capable of using 'join" for multiple core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665797/is-solr-4-0-capable-of-using-join-for-multiple-core)) but is it possible to JOIN 2 cores but both are present at different ports?

For example:

```
Instance 1: http://example:8983/solrInd1/#/person/
Instance 2: http://example:9097/solrInd2/#/engineers/
```

I want to get age, qualification etc from person index and engineering information from engineers index.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no for solr 4 out of the box, but this might change in the future.  And longer answer is yes, by roll your own join plugin, or perform the join on the client(like mongodb). In your example, it might be easier to use multiple cores in a single solr instance.