# Join queries for multiples SOLR cores not working in SOLR 4.3

Tags: solr

As per the threads [Is Solr 4.0 capable of using 'join" for multiple core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665797/is-solr-4-0-capable-of-using-join-for-multiple-core)

and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2272

SOLR 4.x supports join across multiple cores. We tried it and its not giving any response.

Details are as follows:

Two cores:

1. proposition { stockitemid , name }
2. stocks      { mc , counts }

Here "mc" references "stockitemid"

My query:

{!join from=mc to=stockitemid fromIndex=stocks}[image]

Comment: next time, do blur out the ip from google chrome tab title too, or dont include opened tabs in snapshot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below code :

`{!join from=mc to=stockitemid fromIndex=stocks}*:*`