# Solr Join Two datasources with ORing condition

Tags: solr

I have two datasources
DataSourceA (id, keyword) and DataSourceB (pid, pdftext)
How could i get the documents from DataSourceA that has Keyword=Radiology or its matching document in DataSourceB has Radiology in its pdftext.
in other words, as sql statement
`Select A.* from DataSourceA As A inner join DataSourceB As B on A.id=B.pid where A.keyword='Radiology' OR B.pdftext='Radiology'`

i tried
**fq={!join from=pid to=id}pdftext:Radiology OR Keyword:Radiology**
But this didn't work.. any idea?

Comment: Only possible to query the `from` core in a JOIN query. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665797/is-solr-4-0-capable-of-using-join-for-multiple-core

Comment: ONLY?! does that mean the above SQL Query could never be translated into Solr query??

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes. You need to do separate queries across the two cores.

Comment: See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join - "Compared To SQL"

Comment: @arun, thanks for your comments... making two queries will give a result with a lot of duplicate records :( . there should be a more smart solution :)