# Solr Error: QueryComponent.mergeIds(QueryComponent.java:1115) when searching across multiple collections

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We are trying to search collection **Hidden** from collection **Front** using the below url

http://localhost:8983/solr/Front/select?&q=hardware&wt=json&collection=Hidden

This results in the error  QueryComponent.mergeIds as shown in the trace log below.
Querying the Hidden collection directly, returns expected results.

The /select handler for Front collection has the below default config.

```
   <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <int name="rows">10</int>
   <str name="qf">text</str>
   <bool name="preferLocalShards">false</bool>
```

I have tried searching for the mergeIds related errors but couldnt find a solution.
Any suggestions would be welcome.

**Trace Log**

> trace":"java.lang.NullPointerException\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.mergeIds(QueryComponent.java:1115)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleRegularResponses(QueryComponent.java:759)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleResponses(QueryComponent.java:738)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:426)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:156)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2036)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:657)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:464)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:257)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:208)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)\r\n\tat
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)\r\n\tat
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\r\n",

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search in different collection as you tried before. each collection will have different config files. so your FRONT collection has /select handler which can request and get results from only FRONT collection not from Hidden.

In case if you want to use results from other collection index, you should use cross Join.

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665797/is-solr-4-0-capable-of-using-join-for-multiple-core)