# Search/retrieve by a large OR query clause with Solr or Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, nosql

I have a search database of car models: "Nissan Gtr", "Huynday Elantra", "Honda Accord", etc...

Now I also have a user list and the types of cars they like
user1 likes: carId:1234, carId:5678 etc...

Given user 1 I would like to return all the cars he likes, it can be 0 to even hundreads.

What the best way to model this in Solr or potentially another "nosql" system that can help with this problem.

I'm using Solr but I have the opportunity to use another system if I can and if it makes sense.

EDIT:
Solr solution is to slow for Join (Maybe we can try nested). And the current MySQL solution which uses join tables has over 2 billion rows.

Comment: From my understanding in the long term - Its better to go for graph implementation search instead of nosql db. https://neo4j.com/

Answer (score 1):

so, you just want to store a mapping between User->Cars, and retrieve the cars based on the user...sounds very simple:

1. Your docs are Users: contain id (indexed), etc fields
2. one of the field is 'carsliked', multivalued, which contains the set of car ids he likes
3. you have details about each care in a different collection for example.
4. given a user id, you retrieve the 'carsliked' field, and get the car details with a cross collection join

   You could also use nested object to store each liked car (with all the info about it) inside each user, but is a bit more complex. As a plus, you don't need the join on the query.

Solr would allow you many more things, for example, given a car, which users do like it? Elasticsearch will work exactly the same way (and probably many other tools, given how simple your use case seems).

Comment: We would like to return the car details for all the cars the user likes. I guess that's a type of join in Solr/Elasticsearch world?

Comment: one example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665797/is-solr-4-0-capable-of-using-join-for-multiple-core

Comment: nosql is not that much flexible in-terms of JOINS as they are not intended for that.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it - JOINs in Solr will give you data from one collection filtered by another - exactly what you want to do.

Comment: So I cannot accept the answer. It is to slow for our use case. Takes over 90 seconds to return the first result and then cache kicks in. We have millions of users. Even for MySQL with Join table it's billions of rows.

Comment: 90seconds? something must be very wrong or there is a misunderstanding. Can you get the car ids in a single query, and then run another query to get the car details yourself? How long does it take?

Comment: The problem is that each user might have hundreads of cars they like. So I dont want to build a huge query clause.

Comment: Also eventually we will want to do is: give me all the car dealerships around that users area for the cars that he likes

Comment: a clause with hundreds of terms can be ok, why just not try?

Comment: Let me try just query cars directly with multiple ids. This takes for ever: {!join from=cars to=car_id fromIndex=users}user_id:7181402

Comment: Ok query by multiple ids directly against cars is fast.

Comment: This is fast. I.e: card_id:1 card_id:2 ... card_id:100

Comment: just use card_id:(1 2...100) so the request is smaller

Comment: So you don't think that building a query clause with hundreads of keys is bad thing or rather ugly thing?

Comment: No, if it's fast enough, why reject it?